# Any available design pattern for a thread that is capable of executing a specific job sent by another threads?

Tags: java, multithreading, design-patterns

I'm working on a project where execution time is critical. In one of the algorithms I have, I need to save some data into a database.

What I did is call a method that does that. It fires a new thread every time it's called. I faced a runoutofmemory problem since the loaded threads are more than 20,000 ...

My question now is, I want to start only one thread, when the method is called, it adds the job into a queue and notifies the thread, it sleeps when no jobs are available and so on. Any design patterns available or examples available online ?

Comment: 20k threads?! what OS are you using? // anyone?

Comment: @pavelrappo: C# on Windows 7 64-bit seems to be able to handle 18k threads quite nicely. It actually crashed at 20k threads.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Run, do not walk to your friendly Javadocs and look up [`ExecutorService`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html), especially [`Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#newSingleThreadExecutor%28%29).

```
ExecutorService myXS = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();

// then, as needed...

myXS.submit(myRunnable);
```

And it will handle the rest.

Comment: Links to the javadocs and correct class names should make the running-not-walking even faster.

Comment: Thanks.  I never know if people are using Java 6 or Java 7, and if I link to Java 6 (which I am using) people complain.  :-)

Comment: I've been told to link to the latest "current" version and just let the OP sort it out on one occasion, so that's what I do.

Comment: Awesome answer, but don't you think calling Executors.newFixedThreadPool(int x) would enhance the performance since the db can handle multiple requests at a time ?

Comment: @M-T-A In your original question, you said "only one thread".  But you are absolutely correct - if/when you decide to change the thread model, changing one line of code to something like `newFixedThreadPool()` will do the job, with, theoretically, no change to the rest of your code.

Comment: This can also run out of memory, if the queue fills up the available.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you want a worker thread or thread pool pattern.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_pool_pattern

See http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-jtp0730/index.html for Java examples

Answer (score 1):

I believe the pattern you're looking for is called producer-consumer. In Java, you can use the blocking methods on a [BlockingQueue](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html) to pass tasks from the producers (that create the jobs) to the consumer (the single worker thread). This will make the worker thread automatically sleep when no jobs are available in the queue, and wake up when one is added. The concurrent collections should also handle using multiple worker threads.

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for [`java.util.concurrent.Executor`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executor.html)?

That said, if you have 20000 concurrent inserts into the database, using a thread pool will probably not save you: If the database can't keep up, the queue will get longer and longer, until you run out of memory again. Also, note that an executors queue is volatile, i.e. if the server crashes, the data in it will be gone.

Comment: +1 (I'd +2 if I could!) for observing that you've just moved the problem to the queue, and for thinking about the server crash issue.

Comment: The DB stands a better chance of keeping up with a small thread pool than 20000 threads all trying to append to one table.  The 20000 threads are volatile too!